# Formik losing selected values after button click

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with some inputs of type "select". One of them works like: The user selects one service and click on "Add" button to add to a list of services, but after this click, the previously selected values (cliente, funcionario) are getting empty.

```
<Formik
  enableReinitialize
  validationSchema={formSchema}
  onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
    entry
      ? props.setSubmit(values, entry.id)
      : props.setSubmit(values, resetForm);
  }}
  initialValues={defaultValues}
>
  {({
    handleSubmit,
    handleChange,
    values,
    errors,
    touched,
    setFieldValue,
  }) => (
    <Modal
      show={modalForm}
      onHide={handleClose}
      backdrop="static"
      size="lg"
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Preencha o formulário</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Combobox
            label="Cliente"
            name="cliente"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.cliente}
            errors={errors.cliente}
            options={customers}
          />
          <Combobox
            label="Funcionário"
            name="funcionario"
            errors={errors.funcionario}
            onChange={async e => {
              handleChange(e);
              setFieldValue(
                'comissao',
                await loadComission(e.target.value)
              );
            }}
            value={values.funcionario}
            options={employees}
          />
          <hr />
          <CustomCombo
            className="cbwbuton"
            label="Serviço"
            name="servico"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.servico}
            options={services}
          >
            <Button
              variant="outline-primary"
              onClick={() => {
                console.log(values.funcionario);
                addServ(values.servico);
              }}
            >
              <i className="fa fa-plus-circle" />
            </Button>
          </CustomCombo>
```

AddServ function:

```
  const addServ = async id => {
if (id !== '') {
  try {
    const newServ = await api.get(`/service/${id}`);
    await setServicosRealizados([...servicosRealizados, newServ.data]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

};

On screen the values "cliente" and "funcionario" still selected, but these values is empty on output json when I submit. Could someone help me with this issue?